# jarque_bera calculation from scipy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to calculate the Jarque-Bera-Bera test (normality test) on my data that look like that (after chain operation) :

```
ranking Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
Date                
2009-12-29  nan nan nan nan
2009-12-30  0.12    -0.21   -0.36   -0.39
2009-12-31  0.05    0.09    0.06    -0.02
2010-01-01  nan nan nan nan
2010-01-04  1.45    1.90    1.81    1.77
... ... ... ... ...
2020-10-13  -0.67   -0.59   -0.63   -0.61
2020-10-14  -0.05   -0.12   -0.05   -0.13
2020-10-15  -1.91   -1.62   -1.78   -1.91
2020-10-16  1.21    1.13    1.09    1.37
2020-10-19  -0.03   0.01    0.06    -0.02
```

I use a function like that :

```
from scipy import stats

def stat(x):
    return pd.Series([x.mean(),
                      np.sqrt(x.var()),
                      stats.jarque_bera(x),
                      ],
                     index=['Return',
                            'Volatility',
                            'JB P-Value'
                            ])

data.apply(stat)
```

whereas the mean and variance calculation work fine, I have a error message `stats.jarque_bera`function with is :

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 10, index implies 9.
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce and the function works fine for me, by copying the 10 rows of data you are providing above. This looks like a data input issue, where some column seems to have fewer values than the index of that `pd.Series` (effectively somehow `len(data[col]) > len(data[col].index)`). You can try to figure out which column it is by running a naive "debugging" function such as:

```py
for col in data.columns: 
    if len(data[col].values) != len(data[col].index):
        print(f"Column {col} has more/less values than the index")
```

However, the [Jarque-Bera test documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.jarque_bera.html) on Scipy says that `x` can be any "array-like" structure, so you don't need to pass a `pd.Series`, which might run you into issues with missing values, etc. Essentially you can just pass a list of values and calculate their JB test statistic and p-value.

So with that, I would modify your function to

```py
def stat(x):
    return pd.Series([x.mean(),
                      np.sqrt(x.var()),
                      stats.jarque_bera(x.dropna().values), # drop NaN and get numpy array instead of pd.Series
                      ],
                     index=['Return',
                            'Volatility',
                            'JB P-Value'
                            ])
```

Comment: The problem was the pd.Series() inside the stat function.
I did :
```
data.agg([...]) 
```
and it work fine but now how to name the function because I have : 
```
 Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
<lambda> 8.89 9.20 7.63 7.30
<lambda> 15.77 16.19 16.93 17.59
<lambda> -1.04 -0.95 -0.79 -0.61
```
Thx

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you tried. Did you try my suggestion for modifying the function you built?

Comment: I changed my code to : 
data.agg([lambda x: x/mean(),
lambda x: stats.jarque_bera(x.dropna()])
and it work fine but now how to name the function because I have :  
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 
<lambda> 8.89 9.20 7.63 7.30 
<lambda> 15.77 16.19 16.93 17.59 
<lambda> -1.04 -0.95 -0.79 -0.61 

Thx

Comment: How to rename the lambda name ?
Before the new pandas version it was names lambda_1,...so it was easy to use rename function to change them. 
But now I don't know how to proceed inside a chain operation ie :
(df
.agg(...)
.???? here how to rename my function ???
)

Comment: I see. Lambdas are anonymous functions by their nature, so you'd have to rename the column names somehow. One way is to do it like: 

`new = data.agg([lambda x: x.mean(), lambda x: np.sqrt(x.var()), lambda x: stats.jarque_bera(x.dropna())])`
`new.index=['mean', 'sigma', 'JB']`

Comment: I see ! but I don't want to stock "new" variable. I just want a chain operation and would like something like that :
`
data.agg([lambda x: x.mean(), lambda x: np.sqrt(x.var()), lambda x: stats.jarque_bera(x.dropna())]).?????
'
where ???? is a function to replace the lambda with name.

Comment: I think that's a different question to your original one, to be honest.